# Autoform: rendering the selected option that matches an existing value

Tags: meteor

I have [AutoForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) rendering a `<select>` element using an options helper as [recommended in the Readme](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput). This works great for an ***insert***, but I cannot figure out how to get the correct value to be rendered as `selected` on an ***update*** form.

Do I need to access the data context from my js helper file and then use jQuery to set the value after rendering? I tried to access the value from `AutoForm.getFieldValue()`, but it seems to be undefined at the point of `Template.myTemplate.rendered`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the existing document (return value from `MyCollection.findOne()`) as the `doc` attribute on the `autoForm` or `quickForm`, the current value will be selected automatically as appropriate.

```
{{#autoForm doc=doc etc...}}
etc...
{{/autoForm}}
```

And the helper

```
Template.myTemplate.doc = function () {
    return MyCollection.findOne(Session.get("editingId"));
});
```

Or commonly you might be passing in the current document as the template data context using Iron Router, in which case you just do `doc=this` for the `autoForm` component attribute.

Comment: I don't know what I have done differently but it seems to be working somehow.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with a `select-multiple` form? values of the dropdown are populated by a function in the schema, and that seems to be all i'm getting (i.e fields are populated with the document values, but multi-select has no selection). I use `method-update` as the type. any ideas?